# Laravel Route exist in artisan route:list but not in route files

Tags: laravel, routes

When I am checking `php artisan route:list`, the route which i want to redirect  is listed there.

```
for ex: admins.dashboard.panel
```

but I didn't found any related route in route code files.

And I have code in my LoginController as

```
return redirect()->route('admins.dashboard.panel');
```

which is redirecting to login page again.

Comment: Is this route from a package?

Comment: share full route files

Comment: no. it's custom route, user defined

Comment: ok @Sohel0415, here are my all routes

Comment: xvpanel.localhost    | GET|HEAD      | /                                                    | admins.dashboard.panel                                         | Closure

Comment: Auth Middleware is active for your route. Remove the middleware check from the constructor of your controller and you will be redirected to the page without checking your authentication. Middlewares can be applied on your routes and controllers as well. Since you are redirected to your login page this is the first options to check.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I have tried commenting middleware but it's behaving same again.
public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->middleware('guest:admin', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }